# splash screen not working for activity group with tab bar in android

Tags: android

I have a login page, from login page if the user clicks, it will go to tab page. In tab page  I called activity group page. From activity group page it will call home activity page. In home activity I will call webservices. When I click login it shows up with a black screen for a few mins, it take time. That time I have to show splash screen for user until the tab bar is loaded.

I implemented but the below code is not working.
  style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme"> 
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/quest</item> 
</style> 
</resources>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget"
                   android:theme="@style/Theme">
      </activity>
```

Can anybody give sample code?

Thanks

Comment: What I feel you have to implement a sort of multithreading to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {
// stopping splash screen starting home activity.
private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;
// time duration in millisecond for which your splash screen should visible
// to
// user. here i have taken 5 second
private static final long SPLASHTIME = 5000;

// handler for splash screen
private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

        case STOPSPLASH:
            // Generating and Starting new intent on splash time out
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                                         
                             ac.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    // Generating message and sending it to splash handle
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
    splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
}
 }

> try this code for splash screen.
```